# Изменение значения переменной по клику

Tags: java

Нужно написать метод, который бы при нажатии на JPanel сначала записывал в переменную единицу, при повторном нажатии записывал бы 0, при следующем нажатии записывал бы опять единицу и так далее...
Помогите реализовать)

Comment: В Вашем вопросе полностью описан алгоритм действий. Что у Вас не получается?

Comment: Алгоритм то описан, но прошу помощи в синтаксисе самом, не знаю с помощью каких инструментов его реализовать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private int val = 0;
...
public void  switchVal() {
    val = 1 - val;
}
```